# Evaluating $\sum^{7}_{k=1}\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{k^2}+\sqrt[3]{k(k+1)}+\sqrt[3]{(k+1)^2}}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How do I evaluate this?

$$\sum^{7}_{k=1}\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{k^2}+\sqrt[3]{k(k+1)}+\sqrt[3]{(k+1)^2}}$$

I know I'm suppose to use substitutions but didn't work out so far.  Help anyone?

Answer (score 4):

**hint** 
$$(k+1)-k=((k+1)^{\frac{1}{3}}-k^{\frac{1}{3}})((k+1)^{\frac{2}{3}}+(k+1)^{\frac{1}{3}}k^{\frac{1}{3}}+(k)^{\frac{2}{3}})$$

Answer (score 4):

Indeed, make a substitution:

Let $\boxed{x=\sqrt[3]{k}}$ and $\boxed{y=\sqrt[3]{k+1}}$.

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{k^2}+\sqrt[3]{k(k+1)}+\sqrt[3]{(k+1)^2}}=\frac{1}{x^2+xy+y^2}=\frac{y-x}{(y-x)(y^2+xy+x^2)}=\frac{y-x}{y^3-x^3}={y-x}{(k+1)-k}=y-x=\sqrt[3]{k+1}-\sqrt[3]{k}$$

Now, we know that the whole expression can be expressed as:

$$\therefore \sum^{7}_{k=1}\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{k^2}+\sqrt[3]{k(k+1)}+\sqrt[3]{(k+1)^2}}=(\sqrt[3]{2}-\sqrt[3]{1})+(\sqrt[3]{3}-\sqrt[3]{2})+\ldots +(\sqrt[3]{8}-\sqrt[3]{7})=\sqrt[3]{8}-1=\boxed{1}$$

Answer (score 2):

$\Large \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{k^2}+\sqrt[3]{k(k+1)}+\sqrt[3]{(k+1)^2}}=\frac{\sqrt[3]{k}-\sqrt[3]{k+1}}{k-(k+1)}$

$a^3-b^3=(a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2)$